# 'script-src' was not explicitly set but it was?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, content-security-policy

I have added the script-src CSP directive to my AWS CloudFront distribution and my javascript will not run. In the browser console i can see the following error:

```
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security 
Policy directive: "default-src 'self' <<LIST OF DOMAINS>>
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-123abc='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required 
to enable inline execution. Note also that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used
as a fallback.
```

However, my CSP has the following code in it:

```
; script-src 'sha256-123abc=' "
```

When i remove the hash and use 'self', the script-src directive is picked up but that way my script can't run... does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: (1) Chrome diagnostic misleads sometimes (it was fixed in latest version). The inline script can be either `<script>` tag or `<tag onclick='...'>` or `<a href='javascript:...'>`. The last two cannot be resolved by using ``hash-value'` , but Chrome offers to allow these via hashes. (2) You can use `'sha256-123abc='` and `'self'` sunultaneously, why you do remove `'self'` when add `'hash'`? And how do you define is `script-src` directive "picked up" or not?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that the CloudFront distribution was caching the response for a long period of time. I disabled caching and the problem was solved!